# Selenium returns incorrect column count with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape some data from the following website: https://ycharts.com/companies/BP/pe_ratio

The HTML code of the webpage is shown down below, it consists of two tables, i have pasted the code of one table.

The python code i use is this:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='dataTableBox']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody")

tr1 = table.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[1]")

rows = len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")) - 1

cols = len(table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[2]/td"))
```

the rows returns 25 which is correct and the cols returns 11 which is incorrect of course as it should be 2. Does anyone know why? and a solution to this?

I just scraped the data from the rows and i see that it returns more data than is written in the HTLM code below.
I eventually want to scrape all the data from the tables over all pages

```
    <div id="dataTableBox" class="box boxData" ng-controller="HistoricalDataCtrl">
    
<div class="dateRangeControl" 
<div ng-show="initPhase">
<div class="dataColLeft">
    <div class="padR"><table class="histDataTable">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th scope="col" class="col1 colHeadLrg">
            <th scope="col" class="col2 colHeadLrg">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 30, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    20.13
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 27, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    18.81
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 26, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    20.56
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 25, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    20.45
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 24, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    18.62
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 23, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    15.31
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 20, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    14.64
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 19, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    14.31
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 18, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    13.56
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 17, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    15.86
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 16, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    15.86
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 13, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    18.66
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 12, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    18.16
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 11, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    20.76
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 10, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    22.55
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 9, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    21.28
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 6, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    26.30
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 5, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    27.44
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 4, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    27.90
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 3, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    26.87
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">March 2, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    27.13
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">Feb. 28, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    26.34
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">Feb. 27, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    26.54
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">Feb. 26, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    27.51
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">Feb. 25, 2020</td>
            <td class="col2">
                
                    27.72
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Too busy to test but try `cols = len(table.find_elements_by_xpath("./tr[2]/td"))` or ``cols = len(table.find_elements_by_xpath("tr[2]/td"))``.

Comment: you need to make your xpath's relative: the leading dot.

Comment: Thanks it worked with the dot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relative xpaths, I think, are sending you back to the root. To remain at the same spot, you simply need `.` in front of them

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='dataTableBox']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody")

tr1 = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[1]")

rows = len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")) - 1

cols = len(table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr[2]/td"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a requirement to make use of selenium, you can go for requests module to scrape the same content from that page as the tabular content are static. As for the wrong column count is concerned, your defined relative xpath is wrong. However, the following should give you the right count:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

link = 'https://ycharts.com/companies/BP/pe_ratio'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    root = fromstring(res.text)
    table = root.xpath("//*[@id='dataTableBox']//table[@class='histDataTable']")[0]
    tr = len(table.xpath(".//tr[./td]"))
    td = len(table.xpath(".//tr[./td][1]/td"))
    print(tr,td)
```

Output:

```
25 2
```

Comment: How do you define user-agent? Just curious.

Comment: I've defined it within session. Print to see the same headers `print(s.headers)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you trying to get elements inside element you are missing `.` in the `xpath` of the child element.
So first of all the left `table` could be located simply by

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dataTableBox']//tbody)[1]")
```

Now

```
tr1 = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[1]")

rows = len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")) - 1

cols = len(table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[2]/td"))
```